# selecting data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, and it runs very well. I have problem on how to `select` from another table. This code shows how to `select` and `sum()` from 2 different tables. What do I do if I am going to `select` from another table called `tblproductlist`. I am selecting 3 tables in one query. I don't know how to do it. I am searching codes, but it's hard for me to apply.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT (
 SELECT SUM(s.total)-SUM(r.total) FROM rsales AS s WHERE r.pcode=s.pcode
 ) as total, r.pcode 
 FROM rreturn AS r 
 GROUP BY r.pcode;");
```

I tried this code but it returns an error.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT productlist.*,
(SELECT SUM(s.total)-SUM(r.total) 
  FROM rsales AS s 
  WHERE r.pcode=s.pcode) as total, 
r.pcode FROM rreturn AS r 
GROUP BY r.pcode;");
```

for example  I have this ff value.

tblproductlist

```
pcode | pname |
111   | wire  |
```

tablersales

```
|  total    | pcode |
|  200      |  111  |
|  200      |  111  |
```

tablerreturn

```
|  total    | pcode |
|  200      |  111  |
```

so the output after subtracting its total must be something like this.

```
pcode | pname | total
111   | wire  | 200   |
```

Comment: You have already totalled all the records of two tables, do you want this total to be shown along side values from other tables?

Comment: can you post the structure of your tables and the end result that you are expecting ?

Comment: it only sum total values. but i want to select the productname from "tblproductlist" but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you just need to use the `with rollup` option on your group by: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Very loosely speaking, the results of a query need to (a) have the same straucture, (b) be somehow related. The resultset you appear to be trying to build has neither property (at the very least, all pieces of your querys should return the same number of rows)It appears that you need to gain better understanding of sql, besides explaining a little better what you need to do downstream.